# I can't create a virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I try to create a virtual environment with virtualenwrapper-win having it already installed, but when I run the `mkvirtualenv name_env` command I get the error `"mkvirtualenv" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or executable batch file.`
What could be causing this?

i expect `(name_env) C:\Users\NameUser\Desktop\directory>`

Comment: Check if virtualenvwrapper-win is Installed And Add Scripts to PATH

Comment: Why do you need virtualenvwrapper, though? Python 3 comes with venv built in, and they work fine on Windows?

Comment: i checked if virtualenvwrapper-win is installed and it is. How do i add scrips to path? always that i installed virtualenvwrapper i didn't need to do that.

Comment: suggest `python -m venv name_env` , `cd name_env`, then `Scripts\activate` should put you in `(name_env) >`